# Allowing Facebook user to comment on a webpage

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a working website that has comments section for each page (Codeigniter/PHP). It allows only locally registered users to post a comment. Now I also want to allow a non-registered Facebook user to post a comment.

Part around login-in is fine and it's working, the problematic part comes after that.

After the user authenticates with their Facebook account the website receives user access token. A submitted comment will be saved to the database. But, even if the website gets long-lived user access token it will last only for 60 days. After the token expires, when someone visits the page that was commented, the website code will not be able to get name and profile image of the Facebook user that submitted the comment.

I've went through Facebook docs, Graph API, but couldn't find anything helpful. The only solution that I have in mind is to grab profile image and name of the Facebook user and to store that information in the database for later use.

Did I miss something? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're right, you simply store the information on the database and use that ti display the name/picture. The token will always expire but you can have a user update that when they make another comment down the line.

Comment: As no one has given other solution guess that's what I'll do.
After I've posted this question, I thought that maybe I could still pass with direct Graph API calling if the profile is publicly visible but than I could hit the Graph API calling limit if there are a lot of comments and people visiting the page. So I'll use this solution.

Thanks Jester for giving your thoughts on the subject.